# Loading DataTable Into ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, report

I have a datatable that I am filling from a sql adapter.  I am able to get it to successfully show in a datagridview but when I try to do a reportviewer it doesn't work correctly.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "SwipeReport";
da.Fill(dt);

reportViewer1.Reset();
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "POC1.SwipeReport.rdlc";
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SwipeReport", dt));
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I don't believe I'm setting up the report embedded resource correctly as I get a *"report is not specified"* when it's supposed to fill the reportviewer window. Did I implement this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
        // create a new report from the created CrystalReport
        GeneralSupportRpt myDataReport = new GeneralSupportRpt();

        // set the data source of the report
        myDataReport.SetDataSource(dataTable);

        // set the report source of the created “crystalReportViewer”
        // component to the created report

        ReportViewer.ReportSource = myDataReport;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!